# Refactoring slow SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance

I currently have this very very slow query:

```
SELECT generators.id AS generator_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM generator_rows
JOIN generators ON generators.id = generator_rows.generator_id
WHERE
generators.id IN (SELECT "generators"."id" FROM "generators" WHERE "generators"."client_id" = 5212 AND ("generators"."state" IN ('enabled'))) AND
(
  generators.single_use = 'f' OR generators.single_use IS NULL OR
  generator_rows.id NOT IN (SELECT run_generator_rows.generator_row_id FROM run_generator_rows)
)
GROUP BY generators.id;
```

An I'm trying to refactor it/improve it with this query:

```
SELECT g.id AS generator_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
from generator_rows gr
join generators g on g.id = gr.generator_id
join lateral(select case when exists(select * from run_generator_rows rgr where rgr.generator_row_id = gr.id) then 0 else 1 end as noRows)  has on true
where g.client_id = 5212 and "g"."state" IN ('enabled') AND
    (g.single_use = 'f' OR g.single_use IS NULL OR has.norows = 1)
group by g.id
```

For reason it doesn't quite work as expected(It returns 0 rows). I think I'm pretty close to the end result but can't get it to work.

I'm running on PostgreSQL 9.6.1.

Comment: Can you edit the question and explain the logic that you are trying to accomplish?  Often there is a better way to write a query, but it can be hard to figure out the high level logic from a complicated query.

Comment: please, could you add the description of the tables???

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info then **[edit]** your question and add the missing information.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be the query, formatted so I can read it:

```
SELECT gr.generators_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM generators g JOIN
     generator_rows gr
     ON g.id = gr.generator_id
WHERE gr.generators_id IN (SELECT g.id
                           FROM generators g
                           WHERE g.client_id = 5212 AND
                                 g.state = 'enabled'
                          ) AND
      (g.single_use = 'f' OR
       g.single_use IS NULL OR
       gr.id NOT IN (SELECT rgr.generator_row_id FROM run_generator_rows rgr)
      )
GROUP BY gr.generators_id;
```

I would be inclined to do most of this work in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT gr.generators_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM generators g JOIN
     generator_rows gr
     ON g.id = gr.generator_id JOIN
     generators gg
     on g.id = gg.id AND
        gg.client_id = 5212 AND gg.state = 'enabled' LEFT JOIN
     run_generator_rows rgr
     ON g.id = rgr.generator_row_id
WHERE g.single_use = 'f' OR
      g.single_use IS NULL OR
      rgr.generator_row_id IS NULL
GROUP BY gr.generators_id;
```

This does make two assumptions that I think are reasonable:

- `generators.id` is unique
- `run_generator_rows.generator_row_id` is unique

(It is easy to avoid these assumptions, but the duplicate elimination is more work.)

Then, some indexes could help:

- `generators(client_id, state, id)`
- `run_generator_rows(id)`
- `generator_rows(generators_id)`

Answer (score 0):

Generally avoid inner selects as in

```
    WHERE ... IN (SELECT ...)
```

as they are usually slow.

As it was already shown for your problem it's a good idea to think of SQL as of set- theory.

You do *NOT* join tables on their sole identity:

In fact you take (SQL does take) the set (- that is: all rows) of the first table and "multiply" it with the set of the second table - thus ending up with `n times m` rows.

Then the ON- clause is used to (often *strongly*) reduce the result by simply selecting each one of those many combinations by evaluating this portion to either `true` (take) or `false` (drop). This way you can chose *any* arbitrary logic to select those combinations in favor.

Things get trickier with `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN`, but one can easily think of them as to take one side for granted:

- output the combinations of that row *IF* the logic yields true (once at least) - exactly like `JOIN` does
- output exactly *ONE* row, with 'the other side' (right side on `LEFT JOIN` and vice versa) consisting of ALL NULL for every column.

Count(*) is great either, but if things getting complicated don't stick to it: Use Sub- Selects for the keys only, and once all the hard word is done join the Fun- Stuff to it. Like in

```
    SELECT SUM(VALID), ID 
    FROM SELECT
      (
      (1 IF X 0 ELSE) AS VALID, ID 
      FROM ... 
      )
    GROUP BY ID) AS sub
    JOIN ... AS details ON sub.id = details.id
```

Difference is: The inner query is executed only once. The outer query does usually have no indices left to work with **and will be slow**, but if the inner select here doesn't make the data explode **this is usually many times faster** than `SELECT ... WHERE ... IN (SELECT..)` constructs.

Comment: `as they are usually re-evaluated FOR EVERY LINE of your query.` : complete nonsense. Please check the query plan.

Comment: you're right, not evaluated but searched for every ID of the outer query.  But this still makes O(n log n) per search multiplied by the number of ID's. Or am I wrong here as well?

Comment: @wildplasser: In  fact- if the inner query does hold (changing) values from outside the query *has to* be evaluated for every of those values(?!)

Comment: It depends. Basically there are three scenaros: 1) a Merge-join over 2 sorted sets. 2) join over two index-scans (or one idex scan + a sortted set) 3) a hash-join. The choice of plan depends on statistics+tuning (mainly work_mem+random_page_cost)  complexity will be basically 1) N log(N), ~N (upto N log N), and N.